# Dynamic date in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Without manually having to change the date to current date, I'd like to have code which helps to change the date automatically or  auto increment date by one day post 0000hrs in big query

```
AND ((call_date >= "2022-10-01") AND (call_date <= "2022-10-12"))
```

Below is the complete code.

```
WITH_0 AS ( SELECT *, FROM employee_calldata),
 _1 AS (
  SELECT
  call_date AS __call_date__1,
  sub_queue AS __sub_queue__1,
  sum(call_count) as callstaken,
  mode AS __mode__1, `FROM _0 AS _t
WHERE
   (NOT ((call_type) IS NULL)))
   AND ((call_date >= "2022-10-01") AND (call_date <= "2022-10-12"))
   AND (sub_queue = "Customer_Complaints")
   GROUP BY __call_date__1, __sub_queue__1, __mode__1)
   SELECT * FROM _1
```

`

Answer (score 0):

```
DATE((DATETIME_ADD(('2022-10-03 00:00:00'), INTERVAL 100 HOUR)))
```

=> 2022-10-07

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is how you can create rolling windows that increment as the days go forward.

The equivalent to:

```
AND ((DATE(call_date) >= "2022-10-01") AND (call_date <= "2022-10-12"))
```

Is:

```
AND ((DATE(call_date) >= DATETIME_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY) AND (DATE(call_date) <= DATETIME_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 9 DAY)
```

These values will change based on the current date, change the intervals in `DATETIME_SUB and DATETIME_ADD` to change the difference from the current date.

Also some other general comments on your code.

- You do not need brackets on the `WHERE` conditions.
- `(NOT ((call_type) IS NULL)))` can be written as `call_type IS NOT NULL`.
- You do not need your first `SELECT *, FROM employee_calldata` or your `SELECT * FROM _1` as they do nothing extra.

This means your final query can be written as:

```
SELECT
  call_date AS __call_date__1,
  sub_queue AS __sub_queue__1,
  sum(call_count) as callstaken,
  mode AS __mode__1
FROM 
  employee_calldata AS _t
WHERE
  call_type IS NOT NULL
  AND DATE(call_date) >= DATETIME_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY) 
  AND DATE(call_date) <= DATETIME_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 9 DAY)
  AND sub_queue = "Customer_Complaints"
GROUP BY 
  __call_date__1, 
  __sub_queue__1,
  __mode__1
```

Comment: I see an error which says:

 Plx error: #INVALID_ARGUMENT f1::SQL_ANALYSIS_ERROR: No matching signature for operator >= for argument types: STRING, DATETIME. Supported signatures: ANY >= ANY; INT64 >= UINT64; UINT64 >= INT64

Comment: I have edited the question - please try the edited solution. It seems your dates are actually strings so they need to be converted to dates before they can be compared to a date.